# How many sequences strictly growing of length 10 can I write with numbers from 1 to 90?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve this combinatorics exercise. My reasoning is very simple so I don't know if it is correct. 
Let's start with a simple sequence 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. Then I can think of the other sequences that are created by moving the first digit to the left and adding a new one at the end: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11, 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12, etc. So since the multiplication is commutative I can try to calculate the possible sequences by $n(n-1)...(n-9)$ so $90*89*88*87*86*85*84*83*82*81$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following:

- Any subset of $10$ numbers of the $90$ different numbers gives one such sequence (if you order the numbers in the subset increasingly)
- The number of subsets with $10$ elements of the set $\{1,2,\ldots , 90 \}$ is $\binom{90}{10}$

So, you get as number of possible strictly increasing sequences of length $10$
$$\binom{90}{10} = \frac{90\cdot 89 \cdot \ldots \cdot 81 }{10!}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing else than selecting $10$ distinct numbers out of $90$ (to be put in an increasing row afterwards) and there are: $$\binom{90}{10}$$ possibilities.